# IoS Autofill data in login forms is empty in cordova application (using angular)

Tags: ios, angular, forms, cordova, authentication

Cordova 8 / IoS 12 / Angular 6

I have a cordova application with a login form. Everything is working well apart from this.

On ios, the user is prompted by apple to enter a saved password when he focuses in the form.
When the user uses this ios autofill feature, the form doest not detect the new values and the data stays empty. (but the user can see the credentials appearing on the screen)

Here is my login form :

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <input type="email" formControlName="username" name="username"/>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" name="password"/>
        <button class="transparent-button primary">Login</button>
    </form>
```

And in my component :

```
 constructor(
    /* ... */
 ) {
  this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
    username: ["", Validators.required],
    password: ["", Validators.required]
  });

};

login(){
    //this.loginForm.value.username and 
    this.loginForm.value.password stay empty when user 
    autofill
}
```

I also tried with template driven forms : same problem.
Apple is now blocking the publishing of my app because of this.
Is this a known problem of ios/cordova ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're here, please take a moment to upvote the issue on github to get attention from the Angular team https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30616

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I was having this same issue, see my workaround below.

I'm using reactive forms, and was experiencing the issue on a login form where I have just a username and password input. I implemented a workaround where I subscribe to changes on the form and then detect if the native password value is equal the password form field at the time of the change (technically 500ms after the change to wait for the autofill to input the password value). If the two are different I manually override the form value with the native value which triggers validation of the form.

Hope this helps someone!

```
// login-form.component.ts

import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  template: require('./login-form.component.pug')(),
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginFormComponent {

  protected loginForm: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('password') public passwordRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.loginForm = this.getForm();

    // NOTE: this hack triggers form validation on iOS autofill
    this.loginForm.valueChanges
      // wait for 500ms to be sure the autofill is finished with the password field
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe((changes) => {
        // manually fetch the value from nativeElement
        let passVal = this.passwordRef.nativeElement.value; //(<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name="password"]')).value;
        // if the value saved in the form is different from the input, manually update it
        if (passVal !== changes.password) {
          this.loginForm.get('password').setValue(passVal);
        }
      })
    ;
    // NOTE: this hack triggers form validation on iOS autofill
  }

  protected getForm(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
      ]],
      password: ['', [
        Validators.required,
      ]],
    });
  }

  public onSubmit(login: FormGroup) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
// login-form.component.pug
// NOTE: pug + bootstrap 4

h1 Login
form([formGroup]="loginForm", (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)")
  .form-group
    input.form-control(
      formControlName="username",
      name="username",
      type="email",
      placeholder="Username",
      autocomplete="on",
      autocorrect="off",
      autocapitalize="off",
      spellcheck="false",
    )

  .form-group
    input.form-control(
      #password,
      formControlName="password",
      name="password",
      type="password",
      placeholder="Password",
      autocomplete="on",
      autocorrect="off",
      autocapitalize="off",
      spellcheck="false",
    )

  input.mb-3.btn.btn-lg(
    type="submit",
    value="Login",
    [class.btn-outline-primary]="loginForm.valid",
    [class.btn-outline-secondary]="!loginForm.valid",
    [disabled]="!loginForm.valid",
  )
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that came across this in Ionic 5, this [fix](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/928#issuecomment-780448544) did the trick. I've tested this out on regular inputs too (instead of ion-input).

Apparently after the autofill is performed, the Angular (change) event is also triggered on the input field without focus, and this can be used to set the value of that form field. (as shown below):

```
<input ... (change)="form.controls[fieldName].setValue($event.target.value)">
```

As stated in the comment, even though the fix is mentioned in Ionic 3 repo, the user with the solution (as well as myself) tested it out in Ionic 5.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm. I'm having the same issue with Ionic using **ngModel**, but it also occurs using your code with **formGroup**.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Benutzername</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" id="un" type="text" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" clearInput="true" clearOnEdit="false"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Passwort</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" id="pw" type="password" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" clearInput="true" clearOnEdit="false"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

The attributes *autocomplete* and *autocorrect* ([Ionic Input Attributes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/#input-properties)) do not affect the iOS-Autofill feature.

**Example App:**
I have created an example app using the [Ionic Getting Started Guide](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started#cli) to demonstrate this issue:

[Example Login App](https://github.com/jonathanwerle/login-form-ionic-example)

When typing in the credentials by hand, they are being stored in the variables (*password* and *username*) as you can see in the following image:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSybB.jpg)

After setting the AutoFill-credentials in iOS's settings and restarting the simulator, i just clicked into the *Username* field and clicked on "Passwords" in the keyboard's top bar. Then i just selected the user to fill in. Everything looks allright and filled in correctly as you can see in [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zGDi.png)

Then i clicked the **Login**-button and received the output of the **username** and **password** variables as shown in [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiSVA.png)

As you can see, the **username**-field into which i tapped and used the AutoFill-feature has synced its value to its variable. But the password field (into which i never tapped becaus of the AutoFill-feature) **does not** sync its data to its variable.

When i tap into the password-field by hand and use the AutoFill-feature again, the data is synced with its variable correctly: [Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaaLV.png)

The same behavior goes the other way around, just tapping into the password's field using the AutoFill-feature. Then the password-field syncs its value to its variable, but the username-field does not.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good solution but it is working for the time being and apple accepted my app.
Since I can't make the autofill to work correctly, I disabled it :

I changed my password input into a text input so no autofill suggestion is proposed. I also put autocorrect, autocapitalize and autocomplete properties to off.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
    <input type="email" formControlName="username" name="username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="text" formControlName="password" name="password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" class="passwordInput"/>
    <button class="transparent-button primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

And I added this in css to hide the text in the input and simulate the bullets in a real password input :

```
.passwordInput {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Really waiting for a real solution.